# How to solve this very big number using either fermet or eulers theorem

Tags: convergence-divergence, modular-arithmetic

How do i approach this. Am used to only when the mode is prime.

I took euclidean for 5 and 396 and got 396 = 79*5 + 1. But i dont know how to proceed from here

$5^{2159}  mod(396)$

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking to do: I am guessing your goal is to find $5^{2159} \mod 396$. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes. Sorry my mobile screwing up text

Comment: Remark: you don't solve numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Modular Exponentiation Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), it should tell you how to easily solve these problems.